# getting error as could not reach Cloud Firestore backend error on trying to login/authenticate if I disable default service from app engine

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to disable app engine's default service because I had created few API's and deployed in it. Now I don't want those. So I thought of disabling the default app. If disable then the services like firebase login/authentication are not working(I don't know still how many services aren't gonna work. I just encountered this).